# Why is this Low Quality Posts audit designated as spam or offensive?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I'm trying to understand why [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65557651/5320906) is flagged as spam or offensive:

[image]

(The image is truncated on the right-hand side.)

The code seems reasonable, as does the link. There isn't any edit history beyond the initial post except deletion and locking. However, the post has seven downvotes and was closed by Community as spam / offensive within an hour of being posted, so evidently there was something wrong with it.

Can anyone explain:

- why was this flagged as spam / offensive?
- as a reviewer, how can I tell that I should be marking this for deletion (other than visiting the original Q&A)?

Comment: If it was flagged as spam and it contains a link, then I assume that the user who answered is affiliated with the site but didn't disclose that.

Comment: It's impossible to know, but I wonder if that user ended a lot of their posts with a link to the website linked below their answer, and it was seen as "spam" as a result; due to them not disclosing their affiliation. The user has no posts (that aren't deleted), so could well be there are more like them. The audit is "right" in the the answer *was* marked as spam, but I don't understand why myself. Seems like a bad audit example.

Comment: *If* the user did add links to those articles at the end of their posts all the time, my personal opinion would be to remove the link, and leave the rest of the answer intact. The answer still appears to be valid. It *might* be plagarism though; I don't know if they get the same treatment as spam posts (the fact that Community♦ deleted the question suggests it wasn't this though).

Comment: Seems [the domain is used for astroturfing](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=53415231#53415231).

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks, that explains why the post was nuked, and so answers the first part of my question.

Comment: I don't think you truthfully *can* tell that the post is spam from looking at it in solitude. Like I mentioned, I guessed that because it *was* flagged it was as undisclosed affiliation but I would never have come to that conclusion if it wasn't flagged, as people provide links to articles in their answers all the time, myself included, that aren't written by themselves. A "quick" look at the link from the review history doesn't have the authors name either, so that doesn't help come to the conclusion.

Comment: This is not a good audit IMO. It is hard to tell undisclosed affiliation apart from normal answers and sometimes the correlation isn't obvious at all and needs a good amount of digging. Also, a normal reviewer won't have access to the meta data required to make a judgment. This link, for example, was spammed on the SE network 11 times (7 times on SO, 1 on SuperUser and 3 on Unix.SE, in the span of an year) with similar usernames (in 9 cases) and writing styles. Without this metadata, it looks like a normal answer.

Comment: @Yatin Yes, at this point I'm hoping a passing mod will agree to remove this audit and then I can close this as a dupe of one of the other "bad audit" questions.

Comment: I've re-deleted it as R/A, so it should no longer show up as an audit in the Low Quality Posts queue.